# Existence of biholomorphic functions between open subsets of $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

In our course we should decide, whether there exists a biholomorphic mapping between pairs of open subsets of $\mathbb{C}$. The paris are as following:

1. $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{2\}$ and $\mathbb{D}$, which is the unit disk.
2. $\mathbb{C}\setminus(-\infty,0]$ and $H=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:Re(z)>0\}$
3. $S=\{z\in \mathbb{C}: -1 < Im(z)<1\}$ and $\mathbb{C}$.

How can I be sure there really exists one? For example with the first one, I thought of mapping the first subset to $R=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:Re(z)<2\}$, then shifting it over, so I get the left half plane and then use the exponential function to map it to the unit disc. Maybe the only one that wouldn't work is the third one, but how can I prove that?

Answer (score 3):

1. $\mathbb D$ is simply connected and $\mathbb C \setminus\{2\}$ not, so there is no biholomorphic map between them, since biholomorphic maps preserves the simple connectedness.
2. They are biholomorphic, use the [Riemann mapping theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_mapping_theorem), or prove that $f:H\to \mathbb C\setminus (-\infty,0], z\mapsto z^2$ works.
3. Any holomorphic map $\mathbb C \to S$ is constant by Liouville, so it cannot be biholomorphic.
   (As @Don pointed out, $S$ is not bounded. Anyway one can apply Liouville, since $S$ is bounded in the immaginary direction.
   As long as the image of an entire function is not dense in $\mathbb C$, the map is constant, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(complex_analysis)#Entire_functions_have_dense_images)).

Comment: In the third case you can't use Liouville's theorem directly because $S$ is not bounded. Instead, $S$ is biholomorphic to $\mathbb{D}$ again by the Riemann Mapping Theorem. Now, $\mathbb{D}$ is not biholomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$ by Liouville's theorem.

Comment: It is bounded in the immaginary direction, which is enough. You can use Liouville to prove that $f:\mathbb C \to \mathbb C$  holomorphic is  constant, if the image of $f$ is not dense in $\mathbb C$. Check here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(complex_analysis) for a proof.

Comment: Sorry, I edited my comment before reading yours...

Comment: No problem. Your comment was pertinent, and helped to clarify the answer!

Comment: @Desperado sorry, I don't see why 1. couldn't work. Isn't $\mathbb{C}\seetminus\{2\}$ path connected and therefore simply connected?

Comment: There is a hole at 2, a curve around it cannot be contracted, so it is not simply connected. Its fundamental group is indeed $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: @Desperado we haven't had that theorem in our lecture yet (simple connected stays simple connected) and I'm trying to wrap my head around how to prove it without that property. Would it be valid to argument, if such a function would exist, then there would be a holomorphic continuation on $\mathbb{C}$ mapping to $\mathbb{D}$ and using Liouville to show that it must be constant?

Comment: That is a valid argument too.